# Query against XML columns

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a SQL Server 2012 table, where one of the columns is an XML data type.

Below is one of the values:

```
<items>
  <Counter CounterName="processed" CounterValue="70" />
  <Counter CounterName="deferred" CounterValue="1" />
  <Counter CounterName="delivered" CounterValue="70" />
  <Counter CounterName="sent" CounterValue="70" />
  <Counter CounterName="click" CounterValue="2" />
  <Counter CounterName="open" CounterValue="22" />
</items>
```

Question:  How can I write a query that displays all of the above as columns, such as ...

```
SELECT 
   ??? as processed, 
   ??? as deferred, 
   ??? as delivered, --- etc. 
FROM mytable
```

Comment: This article goes into great depth about Querying against XML http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2889/basic-sql-server-xml-querying/

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I'm not real big on 'Here's a link, go fish for the answer' solutions.

Comment: See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887.aspx to learn how to fish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @input TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlCol XML)

INSERT INTO @input VALUES(1, '<items>
  <Counter CounterName="processed" CounterValue="70" />
  <Counter CounterName="deferred" CounterValue="1" />
  <Counter CounterName="delivered" CounterValue="70" />
  <Counter CounterName="sent" CounterValue="70" />
  <Counter CounterName="click" CounterValue="2" />
  <Counter CounterName="open" CounterValue="22" />
</items>'), (2, '<items>
  <Counter CounterName="processed" CounterValue="170" />
  <Counter CounterName="deferred" CounterValue="11" />
  <Counter CounterName="delivered" CounterValue="170" />
  <Counter CounterName="sent" CounterValue="170" />
  <Counter CounterName="click" CounterValue="12" />
  <Counter CounterName="open" CounterValue="212" />
</items>')

SELECT
    ID,
    Processed = xc.value('(Counter[@CounterName="processed"]/@CounterValue)[1]', 'int'),
    Deferred = xc.value('(Counter[@CounterName="deferred"]/@CounterValue)[1]', 'int'),
    Delivered = xc.value('(Counter[@CounterName="delivered"]/@CounterValue)[1]', 'int'),
    [Sent] = xc.value('(Counter[@CounterName="sent"]/@CounterValue)[1]', 'int'),
    Click = xc.value('(Counter[@CounterName="click"]/@CounterValue)[1]', 'int'),
    [Open] = xc.value('(Counter[@CounterName="open"]/@CounterValue)[1]', 'int')
FROM    
    @input
CROSS APPLY
    XmlCol.nodes('/items') AS XT(XC)
```

Gives me an output of:

[image]

Comment: Bingo bango.  Thanks.